# How to code a case block in Haskell that works with Int and Char

Tags: haskell, char, int

I'm working on some Haskell code and stumbled upon a problem. Basically I'm coding a case of block to check the input given by the user that checks if the input is any of the accepted chars as well as Ints

I've tried coding another case block after the first one, but I couldn't work that out. I've tried to code an if-else block that checks if the input is int even before the case block, but that also failed

This is the block of code taken from the middle of the function:

```
if player == 1 then
           do newline
              putStr "Nim: r a / ? / q > "
              inp <- getLine
              let inputs = words inp
                  h = head inputs
              case h of
                 "q" -> do
                    play
                 "?" -> do
                    putStrLn "r is the row and a is amount to remove"
                    putStrLn "The person to remove the last piece wins"
                    play board player

                 -- The case below is the one that I can't seem to make work
                 -- Wrote Int -> do now just to make it clear what I'm looking to do 
                 Int -> do
                    let row = (read(inputs !! 0) :: Int)
                    let row = (read(inputs !! 1) :: Int)
                    if valid board row num then
                       play (move board row num) (next player)
                    else
                       do newline
                          putStrLn "ERROR: Invalid move"
                          play board player
```

Expected scenarios:

```
Nim: r a / ? / q > q
>> "quits game"

Nim: r a / ? / q > ?
>> r is the row and a is amount to remove
>> etc etc...

Nim: r a / ? / q > 2 2
>> "Perform move 2 2"
```

The first two scenarios work. My only problem is to integrate a way to check if the inputs are integers in the case block.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input will *always* be a string. That string may contain a decimal representation of an integer, but that doesn't change anything about the type.

So, what you want to check there is whether it is a string *that can be parsed* as an integer. A nice way to do that is with [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe). That means however you're not checking on `h` itself, but rather on `readMaybe h`, on in fact `mapM readMaybe inputs` (i.e. trying to read *all* of the input, check whether all succeed). But we can still use the same `case` block, we just need to introduce the modified expression to match on with a *pattern guard*. While we're at it, let's get rid of `h` entirely, just put `inputs` in the case expression:

```
          case inputs of
             ["q"] -> do
                play
             ["?"] -> do
                putStrLn "r is the row and a is amount to remove"
                putStrLn "The person to remove the last piece wins"
                play board player

             -- The case below is the one that I can't seem to make work
             -- Wrote Int -> do now just to make it clear what I'm looking to do 
             _ | Just [row, num] <- mapM readMaybe inputs
               -> if valid board row num then
                   ...
```

Comment: This needs a language extension, doesn't it? ViewPatterns or something?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering my question. I tried implementing your suggestion but I get the following error message in ghci: 
``` Variable not in scope: readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int  ```

Comment: Actually my own stupidity caused an error on this one. I didn't even think about the fact that there was a module I had to import. Works perfectly now thanks!

Comment: amalloy: Not anymore – Haskell 2010 added PatternGuards, which is the extension you’re thinking of.